# Functions doesn't work - NodeJs -

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an issue , my functions don't work , I don't know why ?

my code is an interpreter with Nodejs to control a ROBOT to move forward , backward & jump .

This is my code :

```js
/*jshint node: true */
"use strict"; 

var fs = require('fs'); 
var filename = "./robot.txt"; 
var command =  null ; 
var x= 0 , y = 0 , r = 90 , j = 0  , n= 0  , le= 0 , ri= 0 , rep = 0 ,  end = 0, lr= 0 , f = 0 , i= 0 , okC = 0 , b = 0 , t= 0 ; 

try{
 command = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString().split('\r\n'); 
}
catch(e){
 console.error("I can't read from the file " +e); 
}

var line = []; 

robotInterpreter(command); 
console.log('OK' , ' ' + x + ',' + y + ',' + r); 
function robotInterpreter (value){
 for (var i in value) {
  var okC =0 ; 
  var a = value[i].trim(); 

  line.push(a.split(' ')); 
  for(var j in line){
   if(okC === 0)
    verificationOfCommand(line[i][j]);
  }

  if (okC === 1){
   if (rep === 0){
      var c  =  a.substring(n).trim().split(',');
    if(f === 1) verificationOfF(c) ;
    if(b === 1) VerificationOfB(c) ;
       if(t === 1) verificationOfT(c) ;
       if(j === 1) verficationOfJ(c) ;
   }else{
    verificationOfR(c);
   }
   
  }
  
 }
}

function verificationOfE(value){
 if(value.length > 1){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' + i + ':END has 0 parameters, you wrote' + value.length);
 }
}
function verificationOfR(value){
 if (value.length > 1) {
  console.log('ERROR LINE' + i + 'REPEAT has 1 parameters , you wrote' +value.length);
 }else
 if(isNaN(value[0])){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' + i + 'REPEAT parameter 1 requires a number , you wrote' +value[0]);
 //}else
 //if(verificationOfR())
}
}
function verificationOfComment(value){
 var a = value.indexOf('#');
 if (a !== (-1)){
  console.log(value); 
 }
}

function verficationOfJ(value){
 console.log('YES'); 
 if (value.length > 2 ){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' + i + ':JUMP has 2 parameters , you wrote '+value.length); 
 }else
 if(isNaN(value[0])){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' + i + ':JUMP parameter 1 requires a number , you wrote '+value[0]);
 }else
 if(isNaN(value[1])){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' +i+ ':JUMP parameter 2 requires a number , you wrote' +value[1]); 
 }else {
  jump(value[0],value[1]); 
  j= 0; 
 }
}

function verificationOfF(value){
 if (value.length > 1){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' +i+ ':FORWARD has 1 parameter , you wrote ' + value.length);
 }else
 if (isNaN(value[0])){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' +i+ ':FORWARD parameter 1 requires a number , you wrote '+ value[0]); 
 }else{
  forward(value[0]);
  f = 0 ; 
 }
}

function verificationOfT(value){
 if (value[0].trim() === "left"){
  le = 1 ;  
 }
 if(value[0].trim() === "right"){
  ri= 1; 
 }

 if (value.length > 2){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' +i+ ':TURN has 2 parameters , you wrote '+value.length);
 }else
 if(isNaN(value[1])){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' +i+ ':TURN parameter 2 requires a number , you wrote'+value[1]);
 }else
 if (le === 0 && ri === 0) {
  console.log('ERROR LINE' +i+ ':TURN parameter requires a left/right , you wrote'+value[0]);
 }else{
  if (le === 1) {
   turnL(value[1]);
   t = 0 ; 
   le = 0 ; 
  }
  if (ri === 1) {
   turnR(value[1]); 
   t = 0 ; 
   ri= 0 ;  
  }
 }

}

function VerificationOfB(value){
 if(value.length > 1){
  console.log('ERROR LINE'+i+ ':BACKWARD has 1 parameter , you wrote' + value.length);
 }else
 if(isNaN(value[0])){
  console.log('ERROR LINE' +i+ ':BACKWARD parameter 1 requires a number , you wrote'+value[0]); 
 }else{
  backward(value[0]);
  b = 0;
 }
}

function verificationOfCommand(value){
 if(value === "FORWARD"){
  f = 1 ; 
  okC = 1 ; 
  n = value.length;
 }else
 if(value === "BACKWARD"){
  b= 1 ; 
  okC = 1 ; 
  n = value.length; 
 }else
 if (value === "JUMP"){
  j = 1 ; 
  okC = 1 ; 
  n = value.length; 
 }else
 if(value === "TURN"){
  t = 1 ; 
  okC = 1 ; 
  n = value.length ; 
 }else
 if (value === "REPEAT"){
  lr = i ; 
  rep = 1 ; 
  n = value.length; 
 }else
 if(value === "END"){
  end = 1 ; 
  n = value.length; 
 }
}

function forward (value){
 x = x + parseInt(value); 
}

function backward (value){
 x = x - parseInt(value); 
}

function turnL(value){
 var k = parseInt(value); 
 while (k >= 360){
  k= k - 360 ; 
 }
 if (r + k > 360) 
  r = (r+ k) - 360 ; 
 else
  r = r+ k ; 
 if(r === 360 )
  r= 0 ; 
}

function turnR(value){
 var k = parseInt(value); 
 while(k >= 360){
  k = k - 360 ; 
 }
 if (r - k < 0 )
  r = 360 - (k-r); 
 else 
  r = r - k ; 
 if (r === 360)
  r = 0 ; 
}

function jump(var1, var2){
 x = parseInt(var1); 
 y = parseInt(var2); 
 j = 0;
}
```

The robot.txt contains :

```
# Move
FORWARD 200
COMMAND_WITH_ERROR 
BACKWARD 10
```

and it should print :

```
OK 200, 0, 90
ERROR LINE 2: Unknown command COMMAND_WITH_ERROR
OK 190, 0, 90
```

but my program prints only : x= 0 , y = 0 , r = 90

Anything wrong ?

PS : I used jshint and i got this error :

```
intersting.js: line 39, col 33, 'c' used out of scope.
```

Comment: Well, the linter warning is certainly correct, you're initialising the variable in the then-branch and trying to use it in the else-branch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , but i didn't understand you well , could you please clearify things to me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rep === 0){
     var c  =  a.substring(n).trim().split(',');
     ...
     // c is defined here!
     verificationOfR(c);
   } else {
     // c is not defined here!
     verificationOfR(c);
}
```

In your code above you did not define c in the else statement. In an if else statement it will take one path or the other, not bits from both.

You would need to do the following

```
if (rep === 0){
     var c  =  a.substring(n).trim().split(',');
     ...
     verificationOfR(c);
   } else {
     var c  =  a.substring(n).trim().split(',');
     // c is *now* defined here!
     verificationOfR(c);
}
```